# How do I store an image in a vector?

Tags: c#, arrays

Can you store an image in a vector? If yes, how do you do it? I know that in C# you do it with pointers.. What's the counterpart for pointers here?

EDIT:

```
byte[] pngBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\myphoto.png");
List<byte[]> images = new List<byte[]>();
images.Add(pngBytes);
```

EDIT2:

```
public class WineModel
{
    public WineModel (byte[] bytes, string description)
       {
           this.Bytes = bytes;
           this.Description = description;
        }

public byte[] Bytes {get;set;}
public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

EDIT3:

```
 var button = new KinectTileButton
              {
                  Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),

                  Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
                   Tag = wineModel
              };
```

Code XAML:

```
  <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">
            <!-- items for design layout.  They will be replaced at runtime. -->
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="1" Click="KinectTileButton_Click" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="2"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="3"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="4"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="5" Click="KinectTileButton_Click_1" />
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="6"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="7"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="8"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="9"/>
            <k:KinectTileButton Label="10"/>

        </WrapPanel>
```

Comment: do you want to save an array of type image?

Comment: What type of image do you have? Do you generate it in-memory, or load it from a PNG or something else?

Comment: It's an PNG image and I have it on my computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot vectorize a PNG. Simply because the image is saves as pixels having a particular color.

You can save the image in an array though, but then then would be bytes.

To save the image in a list define this class:

```
public class ImageInfo
{
    public ImageInfo(Image image, string description)
    {
        this.Image = image;
        this.Description = description;
    }

    public Image Image {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And in your reading method:

```
List<ImageInfo> images = new List<ImageInfo>();

Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\myphoto.png");

images.Add(new ImageInfo(image, "this is a description"));

...

pictureBox1.Image = images[0].Image;
```

Comment: I think that what you say is good but the vectore you compiled is undetermined, right? I want to add an image for the point (0) in the vector pngByes, another image for point(1) and so on. Can it be done?

Comment: What is the end result you expect? A list of images? A list of points / vectors?

Comment: A list of images with descriptions for each one

Comment: Then you should create a list of them. I will update my answer.

Comment: I've edited my post.. the images are stocked dynamically, right? But I have 8 images and for each image I have a specific description. How do I find out on which point on the vector is a certain image?

Comment: You could create a custom class, containing the additional information. I will post an update.

Comment: I've created the class you said.. just that I've named it differently. Right now my code doesn't display the images. Right? It only reads them... what should I add to display them?

Comment: this is how my class looks like.i`ve made the changes as well and this is the error i get "Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>.Add(byte[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: yes, you were right, but when I compile the program it doesn't display any image

Comment: You should use a PictureBox in Windows Forms to show the image. You could load the image from file directly and assign it to the Image property of the PictureBox.

Comment: i had an intruction foreach, that display my images in to a "kinectTitlebutton". You can see my code, the code in my poste and how was displayed, my image. Was not displayed in a picturebox.

Comment: I don't know anything about Kinect programming. I suggest to move that part into new question.

Comment: If this post was helpful, please don't forget to mark your question as answered.